# Top-level await is not available when importing jQuery in a component in Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, async-await, vite

I am trying to build my project with SSR and I've run into an error with jQuery which is used in a number of my components. SSR does not work well with jQuery, so I wanted to implement it dynamically for client. I have the main jQuery in index.html script src.

Inside of my components for example I have  `import('jquery-flexdatalist/jquery.flexdatalist');`

This import breaks SSR. I have tried to write it as

```
let jQuery
if (!import.meta.env.SSR) {
jQuery = await import('jquery-flexdatalist/jquery.flexdatalist');
}
```

This works in dev mode, but when I build the project I get an error " Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("es2019") ". I'm using vite and have tried switching between es2015-es2019, `build: { target: "es2017", }` no results. I'm either looking on how to solve this import or how to properly implement jQuery for client side.

Comment: This is still a problem https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/253 . Don't use top-level await if you have problems with it. This was solved with async iife previously.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative way to import jQuery and so far was unable to. Adding it to script src in index.html also does not work

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the problem is with jQuery. It's jQuery plugin in the question, not jQuery itself